# The Eleavated Button is Not Listening the to Changes While Onpress that Button

Tags: flutter, dart, provider

```
void _activebutton() {
    controller = TextEditingController();
    print(controller);
    _isButtonActive = !_isButtonActive;
    controller.addListener(
      () {
        final _isButtonActive = controller.text.isNotEmpty;
        this._isButtonActive = _isButtonActive;
      },
    );
    notifyListeners();
  }
```

The _isButtonActive variabledefault value is assigned to false..

```
Consumer<PasswordVisibilty>(
                            builder: (context, mybutton, child) {
                          return ElevatedButton(
                            style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                              primary: appPrimaryColor, // background
                              onPrimary: Colors.white, // foreground
                              fixedSize: Size(context.screenWidth * 0.80,
                                  context.screenHeight * 0.07),
                              onSurface: appPrimaryColor,
                              shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
                              ),
                            ),
                            onPressed: mybutton.buttonactive
                                ? () {
                                    mybutton.activebutton();
                                  }
                                : null,
```

The elevated button is wrapped with Consumer but its not changing the state while onpress the button

Comment: Where are you changing the value of `mybutton.buttonactive` ?

Comment: buttonactive is getter one assigned like this   get buttonactive => _isButtonActive;

Comment: the default value of _isButtonActive is false after that inside the function _activebutton i am changing the value of _isButtonActive = !_isButtonActive; so it will became true when i type in textfield right but its not listening to that

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try.

```
ElevatedButton(
    // ...
    onPressed: this._isButtonActive ? mybutton.activebutton : null,
)
```

Note that you can use the [tear-off instead of a closure](https://dart.dev/guides/language/effective-dart/usage#dont-create-a-lambda-when-a-tear-off-will-do).

Also, the double assignment in the listener is no necessary:

```
controller.addListener(() => _isButtonActive = controller.text.isNotEmpty);
```

Comment: still the button is not active if i type something in textfield

Comment: @RakulAgn If you have created a `StatefulWidget`. you may need to update `_isButtonActive` inside a call to `setState()` as in `setState(() => _isButtonActive = controller.text.isNotEmpty)`

Comment: Actually I Wrote the Logic on Seprate File with ChangeNotifyer it's Necessary to Create Statefullwidget and Provide SetState ?

Comment: @RakulAgn The use of a flag such as `_isButtonActive` requires `setState()` and therefore a stateful widget.

Comment: Yeah but we do like this ```class DateSelection extends ChangeNotifier {
  var _isButtonActive = false;

  onDateSelection() {
    _isButtonActive = !_isButtonActive;
    notifyListeners();
  }
}``` For This Why We Need SetState we Can this Go with Stateless Widget Right ?

Comment: @RakulAgn Your not showing enough code to judge that. In my experience a StatefulWidget is necessary to rebuild your tree when a flag is changed.